# Which system is more efficient?

Tags: technic, motor, gears

I got a few XL power functions motors, and want to combine them to make a racing car. Let's get to right to the question:

Which one save the most torque power? This one...
[image]

...or this one?

[image]

PS: It is okay if you warn me that even with three XL motors, the car won't work.

Comment: I assume that the first one is less likely to damage the 8-tooth gears, if that's a possibility, which it probably isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The torque in both versions would be the same.

Your first version just adds 3 of these gears:

[image: gear 3648]

The ratio between them is 1:1 so it will be the same as if you connect the axle straight into those small gears, as you do in the second image.

(Well, technically speaking, having 3 more gears in the mix will sacrifice some power to friction, but the theory is the same.)

---

Note, this answer assumes you aren't also running an axle through both these gears in your first image.

[image: gear 3648] [image: gear 3649]

If you are, then it simply will not work.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was looking for :)